# silverlight crossdomainpolicy.xml file problem

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, https, cross-domain, xml-rpc

I have made a silverlight application and I have hosted it on my localhost IIS. and the URL of this application is `http://localhost/default.aspx` I have developed and other xml-rpc server which is also running on same machine and its address is `https://localhost:8000`, I am having problem in calling the remote functions from the url `https://localhost:8000` I want to know that where should I place the clientaccesspolicy.xml and what should be the contents of that xml file specifically for this case?

Comment: User for 7 Months, asked 27 questions, only accepted 16% of them, is there something you can do about that?

Comment: what do you mean? Is it answer to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to put a **clientaccesspolicy.xml** file in the root folder of the web site at port 8000.

It could be something like this (although **you should decide what the proper security would be best for you scenario**):

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<access-policy>
    <cross-domain-access>
        <policy>
            <allow-from http-request-headers=""*"">
                <domain uri=""*""/>
            </allow-from>
            <grant-to>
                <resource path=""/"" include-subpaths="" true""/>
            </grant-to>
        </policy>
    </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```